Adding objects within a specific Array type in React TypeScript
I'm writting the shchema of my web app by Zod and I'm creatig different message errors to input objects. A minimum length for one and a user verified in the other case.
The minimum length condition has been resolved but the user approval condition hasn't. The idea is to fetch users from Jsonplaceholder API and verified if user and password (input objects) match with username and zipcode (Jsonplaceholder), respectively. Therefore, I tried to create an Array with users coming from Jsonplaceholder but for some reason, the Array which I created and pushed the elements, shows the elements in Chrome, but doesn't count elements as an array elements (I will post a photo to explain the last part better).
Users.ts:
import { z } from "zod";
import { APIUsers } from "../types";

const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
const users: APIUsers[] = [];

fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json() as Promise<APIUsers[]>;
  })
  .then((data) => users.push(...data));

export const userSchema = z.object({
  user: z.string().min(1, { message: "Ingresar Usuario" }),
  password: z.string().min(1, { message: "Ingresar Contraseña" }),
});

export type Users = z.infer<typeof userSchema>;

console.log(users);


index.ts:
export type APIUsers = {
  username: string;
  address: {
    zipcode: string;
  };
};

And this is what Chrome print:
Chrome Outut
It doesn't allow me choose an Array's element
